# findElement and findElements abstract methods could have been directly declared in WebDriver interface?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

What is the need of SearchContext interface in the Selenium? It has two abstract methods findElement and findElements. What is the need of extending in WebDriver interface? findElement and findElements methods could have directly declared in WebDriver interface?